# criar dois markers com drag drop no google maps api

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Fala galera,

Estou criando um mapa onde a idéia é a pessoa poder inserir um pin nele e logo na sequencia inserir outro pin, quando ele inserir o segundo pin,  uma linha entre os dois pins apareceria informando a distancia entre eles. Salvaria a lat/long dos dois pins em um mysql para poder exibir varios 'trajetos de dois pontos' no mapa. Alguem tem alguma ideia de como eu poderia fazer isso ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Criando um mapa e adicionando 2 marcadores "arrastaveis":

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatlng
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

// Place a draggable marker on the map
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng1,
    map: map,
    draggable:true,
    title:"Marcador 1"
    });

  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng2,
        map: map,
        draggable:true,
        title:"Marcador 2"
    });
```

Calcular distancia:

```
function CalcularDistancia(latlng1, latlng2) {
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
            origins: [latlng1],
            destinations: [latlng2],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING // mude de acordo com seu proposito
        }, callback);
    }
function callback(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            alert("Distância:" + response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text);

        }
    }
```

Comment: mas como eu faria para adicionar o primeiro pin, e depois o segundo ? Assim ele adiciona os dois de uma vez....

Comment: Separe em uma função e chame ela quando precisar!